Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.?
I don't know where the problem is, the local storage is not working and the screen is white "browser"
   5 | const getFromLocalStorage = () => {
   6 |     if (typeof window !== undefined) {        
>  7 |         const value = localStorage.getItem("theme");
     |                       ^
   8 |         return value || "light";
   9 |     }
  10 | };

I tried to find the problem and rewrite the code again , but still the same problem

The error and the code shown imply a mismatch between what's actually executing and what you're looking at.  setItem isn't being called here.

where is the localStorage object being instantiated?

Hmmm, not sure I follow because the error posted in the title differs from the code, but yes, setItem does take 2 parameters, the key you will use to retrieve it, and the desired value.
